# load text file list into <option> tags

Tags: php, html, text-files, html-select

Im working on a **PHP** project that involves selecting a song, hitting the submit button and then having the **PHP** loading the song player to the correct option.

For the song selection I want to load these options from a *txt* file with the following formatting:

```
<br />
<code>All For Love <br /> Break Free <br />Come to the River <br />For You Nam    </code>
```

---

Which I want to be processed to end up like this:

```
<br /> <code>
< option value="All For Love"> All For Love< /option> <br /> 
< option value="Break Free">Break Free< /option> <br /> 
< option value="Come to the River">Come To The River< /option> <br /> 
< option value="For Your Name">For Your Name< /option> <br />
```

---

How would I go about achieving this?
[project so far](http://hzy.im/mildred)

Comment: Put some effort first and ask more specific question when you find a problem you cannot solve.

Comment: Many freshers & freelancers may not be able to solve a problem quite efficiently & quickly. And this SO is probably the best area to get all your queries to get answered or shown the proper way. Please try to be lenient in these programming issues, where POs are new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$songs = file('path/to/file/with/songs.txt');
$options = '';
foreach ($songs as $song) {
    $options .= '<option value="'.$song.'">'.$song.'</option>';
}
$select = '<select name="songs">'.$options.'</select>';

echo $select;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$file_array = file($file_path);
foreach ($file_array as $song)
  echo '<option value="'.$song.'">'.$song.'</option>'.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$file_path = 'data/canada.txt'; 
$file_array = file($file_path); $options = '';

foreach ($file_array as $song){   
   $options .= ''.$song.''; 
}


 $select = ''.$options.'';

 echo $select;
```